# Protractor cucumber html report is generating only after 2nd run?

Tags: html, protractor, cucumber, report

When i try to run my code it is generating html report only after 2nd run.
In the first run it is generating the json file and then after the second run, by using the generated json file and creating the HTML report

Please tell me how to generate html report by running only once.

below is code i tried

hook.js

```
const {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function ({After}) {

   After(function(scenario,done)
{
const world = this;
console.log('in after block')
if (scenario.result.status === 'failed') {
console.log('in after block inside')

    browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (stream) {
        let decodedImage = new Buffer(stream.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ''), 'base64');
        world.attach(decodedImage, 'image/png');
        console.log('screenshot successful');
    }).then(function () {
        done();
    });
}else {
    done();
}
});


       });
```

index.js

```
var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

var options = {
        theme: 'bootstrap',

    output: 'cucumber-report.html',
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    launchReport: true,
    screenshotsDirectory: 'screenshots123',
    takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
     //screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
    storeScreenshots: true,

};

reporter.generate(options);
```

Index.js

```
var reporter = require('cucumber-html-reporter');

var options = {
    theme: 'bootstrap',
    jsonFile: 'C:/Users/pc/ProtractorCucumber/htmlReport/cucumber_html_reporter/report.json',
  //  jsonFile: 'C:/Users/pc/ProtractorCucumber/htmlReport/cucumber_html_reporter/cucumber-report.json',
    output: 'C:/Users/pc/ProtractorCucumber/htmlReport/cucumber_html_reporter/cucumber-report.html',
   // output: 'report123.html',
    reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
    launchReport: true,
    screenshotsDirectory: 'screenshots123',
    takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
     //screenshotsSubfolder: 'images',
    storeScreenshots: true,

};

reporter.generate(options);
```

Comment: The root cause is cucumber json report file isn't generated before creating HTML report from the json report file at the first time.  When the 2nd running finish, the cucumber json report file of the 2nd running still not generated, and the script use the json report of the 1st running to create the HTML report.  So the HTML report is always base on the previous running result, not the current running.   You need to figure out how to make the json report file be created prior to create HTML report.

Comment: Please give the version of your cucumber-js

Comment: i am using cucumber 5.0.2 version

Comment: My a github project explains how to do in detail and with code. https://github.com/yongcy/automation/tree/master/protractor/protractor-cucumber4-scaffold.

Comment: @yong Sorry for the late reply. Its working thanks

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber-html-reporter will require the JSON file created by cucumber after the execution.

Please refer the following snippet which has exception handled before calling `generate` function of **cucumber-html-report**.

```
const Cucumber = require('cucumber');
import { browser } from 'protractor';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { config } from '../config/config';
import { defineSupportCode } from "cucumber";
import * as reporter from 'cucumber-html-reporter';
import { mkdirp } from 'mkdirp';

defineSupportCode(function ({ registerHandler, registerListener, After, setDefaultTimeout }) {
    setDefaultTimeout(10 * 1000);
    let jsonReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/json";
    let htmlReports = process.cwd() + "/reports/html";
    let targetJson = jsonReports + "/cucumber_report.json";


//BeforeFeature
    registerHandler('BeforeFeature', function (event, callback) {
        browser.get(config.baseUrl);
        callback();
    });

    After(function (scenario) {
        let world = this;
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            return browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (screenShot) {
                // screenShot is a base-64 encoded PNG
                world.attach(screenShot, 'image/png');

            });

        }

    })

    let cucumberReporterOptions = {

        theme: "bootstrap",
        //theme: "foundation",
      //  theme: "simple",
        jsonFile: targetJson,
        output: htmlReports + "/cucumber_reporter.html",
        reportSuiteAsScenarios: true,
        launchReport: false

    };

    let logFn = string => {
        if (!fs.existsSync(jsonReports)) {
            mkdirp.sync(jsonReports);
        }
        try {
            fs.writeFileSync(targetJson, string);
            reporter.generate(cucumberReporterOptions); // invoke cucumber-html-reporter
        } catch (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(`Failed to save cucumber test results to json file. 
                             Failed to create html report.
                             `);
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    };
    let jsonformatter = new Cucumber.JsonFormatter({
        log: logFn
    });
    registerListener(jsonformatter);
})
```